# Send ajax request when app close

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm working on cordova with jquery mobile and I need that when the user pauses or closes the app, It will send an ajax request to a server. I added

```
document.addEventListener("pause",  function(){


        if(!isPayed){
            request = $.ajax({
                url: URL + "removeSit.php",
                type: 'POST',
                data: datastring,
                crossDomain: false,
                cache: false,
                success: function(result){

                    $.mobile.navigate("#homePage");

                },
                error: function(error){

                }
            }); 

        }
    }, false);
```

If i pause the app, it works, but if i close immediately the app (through menu button), it doesn't send the request. I tried also with the event "menubutton" but with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

**1.App Closing ajax call**

You have to prevent closing app

```
function onDeviceReady(){
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}
function onBackKeyDown(){
    return false;
    //////////// your ajax call here
    $.ajax({
        url: "demo_test.txt", 
        success: function(result){            
        navigator.app.exitApp();  ///// on success close app
    }});
}
```

**2.App pause ajax call**

```
document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);    
function onPause() {
    /// your ajax call here
}
```

If user kills minimized app from task manager  app cant send ajax request.
to do this you have to set interval to check app closed or not